# Pandas Group by 2 columns and count instances of T and F to create 2 new columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns: `source_name`, `dest_address`, and `fall_between`.  I would like to group by the first 2 columns and create 2 new columns based off of the `fall_between` column.  This is what the df looks like:

```
df           
   source_name  dest_address   fall_between
0  source_1     72.21.215.90   False
1  source_1     72.21.215.90   False
2  source_1     72.21.215.90   False
3  source_1     72.21.215.90   False
4  source_1     131.107.0.89   False
5  source_1     131.107.0.89   False
6  source_2     69.63.191.1    False
7  source_2     69.63.191.1    True
8  source_2     69.63.191.1    True
9  source_2     69.63.191.1    True
10 source_2     69.63.191.1    True
```

Desired output:

```
df
   source_name  dest_address   true_count  false_count
0  source_1     72.21.215.90   0           4
1  source_1     131.107.0.89   0           2  
2  source_2     69.63.191.1    4           1
```

I was using the following but I am not getting a count if it is 0. What is a better way to do this?

```
df[df['fall_between'] == True].groupby(['source_name','dest_address']).size().reset_index(name='true_count')
df[df['fall_between'] == False].groupby(['source_name','dest_address']).size().reset_index(name='false_count')
```

Comment: What will became if you substitute `size()` with `count()`?

Comment: I get the same result @AlexYu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pd.crosstab([df.source_name, df.dest_address], df.fall_between).reset_index()

fall_between  source_name  dest_address  False  True
0               source_1  131.107.0.89      2     0
1               source_1  72.21.215.90      4     0
2               source_2   69.63.191.1      1     4
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for.  I will be sure to read the doc as I have never used crosstab before.  Thank you @yatu

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to include the 0s, I'm wondering if it makes more sense to use `.value_counts()`.

Take a look: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html